# How to sort a four-column database into groups by sums of 30 found from the fourth column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting

I have an excel database with four columns (A, B, C, D). The fourth column (D) has integers. I want to know how to sort the data by summed groups of 30 from the data in D.

For example this data:

[Four columns with the first three columns of unnecessary data and the fourth column containing (7,5,6,4,12,9,8,9)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KlyW.jpg)

I want sorted to become

[Two groups with the first group (7,5,6,12) and the second (9,8,9,4). The data in the previous three columns of course is preserved and follows their respective numbers.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqs7f.jpg)

Please let me know how I can do this. Even though my images are of Excel 2003, I have access to higher versions.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That's not 'sorting', but a much more complex problem.

It probably is NP-hard, meaning there is no general computational algorithm even *possible* (expect brute-force trials). *No way* to do in Excel without extensive coding.

Comment: Would you happen to know how the pseudocode for that would work? With that direction I'd like to try my hand at VBA.